# Trace of tensor product

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I am currently struggeling with the following problem:

> Imagine that you have 4 vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then you want to calculate $\hbox{trace}(v_4 \otimes v_3 \cdot  v_1^T \otimes v_2^T)$. What is this?

I came across this thing in Theoretical Physics dealing with density matrices, but I do not know how to calculate this.

Comment: I think you just need to figure out what $\otimes$ means, since I guess the "$\cdot$" stands for the usual matrix product

Comment: $\otimes $ is the tensor product

Comment: My guess is that $v_4 \otimes v_3 \cdot  v_1^T \otimes v_2^T$ means $v_4 v_1^T \otimes v_3 v_1^T$.  And $v_4 v_1^T$ and $v_3 v_1^T$ are the matrices created by the outer product.  But it is quite a wacky notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\trace}{\mathrm{trace}}
\newcommand{\tr}{\mathrm{tr}}
\newcommand{\Tr}{\mathrm{Tr}}
$

This is a variation of physicist Dirac, bra-ket notation. In a more standard bra-ket notation your equation reads

$$ \trace ( |v_4,v_3 \rangle \langle v_1,v_2 | ) = \trace ( |v_4 \rangle \langle v_1 | \otimes |v_3 \rangle \langle v_2 | ). $$

Using $ \trace ( A \otimes B) = \trace (A) \,\trace (B)$, this evaluates nicely to  (simply "permute cyclically the kets to the left")

$$ \langle v_1 | v_4 \rangle \langle v_3 |v_2  \rangle \, $$

This is why this notation is indeed useful. By the way, the above means

$$ v_1^T v_4 \,\, v_3^T v_2 \,. $$

In bra-ket notation $|v\rangle$ denotes a vector and $\langle v|$ its adjoint under the scalar product you are using. In your case, it seems you are using real field and (standard) real scalar product

$\langle x|y\rangle = x^T y $

Comment: how did you transform the two tensor products of one projection into two projections and one tensor product? do you know any reference for this? but yes, this looks good.

Comment: Physicists often don't write the tensor product between two vectors. Frequent notations are: $ |x\rangle \otimes | y\rangle = |x\rangle | y\rangle = |x, y\rangle $. Your expression was: $|v_4 \rangle |v_3 \rangle \langle v_1 | \langle v_2 | = |v_4 \rangle  \langle v_1 | \otimes |v_3 \rangle \langle v_2 | $. You basically insert the simbol $\otimes$ only when it's needed to avoid confusion. In this last equation the tensor product is between matrices.

Comment: @Lipschitz you are very welcome. NB note that $ |v_4 \rangle \langle v_1 | $ is not a projector unless $ \langle v_1 |v_4 \rangle =1$ (which again is easy to show with this notation).

Comment: thank you. Honestly, I think this notation is so confusing that the only way to get used to it is using this notation...

Comment: How come that $trace(\vert v_4\rangle \langle v_1\vert) = \langle v_1\mid v_4\rangle$, whereas in the case of $\vert v_3\rangle \langle v_2\vert$, it is the other way around?

Comment: @gen you are right, that is a typo. The first equation is correct. Then swap 2 with 3.